# How can I get just the "free swap" value from the output of the "free" command?

Tags: command-line, swap

I know that `free -m` will print all the free and used memory values, including the values for Swap.  However, I want to only get the numerical value for the amount of free swap on my system.

How can I get just the 'free swap' value from the `free` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`man free`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/free.1.html):

```
FILES
   /proc/meminfo
          memory information
```

You can parse that file directly instead of going via `free`:

```
$ awk '/SwapFree/' /proc/meminfo
SwapFree:        4007168 kB
```

Or, for only the value in MB:

```
$ awk '/SwapFree/ {print $2 / 1024}' /proc/meminfo
3913.25
```

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to see if it was possible to do this without additional commands other than `free -m`, but I was unable to find such a solution.

This command, which can be run directly on the command line, can provide you the value of the "Free Swap" from `free -m`.  You can put this into a script if you want to have a command you can call easily to run this:

```
free -m | grep "Swap" | awk '{ print $4 }'
```

Comment: Not really sure why you went and made this a script.  This works as a one-liner command when run directly on the command line.

Comment: I made a script to store only.

Comment: there's no need for that in your answer - your original question didn't ask for a script.  I've amended your answer so that it's a little more expanded, such that it has better grammar *and* says it can be run as a one-liner or added to a script.  (I did similar revisions to your question, to make it a little better)

Comment: Get rid of grep, awk can search patterns